# Could not load kernel32.dll when loading Seriog.Sinks.SystemConsole through AssemblydependencyResolver.ResolveUnmanagedDllToPath

Tags: serilog

We are referencing Serilog Nuget package in our .Net 6 application. Then we use AssemblydependencyResolver.ResolveUnmanagedDllToPath to load the application assembly as plugins. It can't find the kernel32.dll which is refereced via Serialog.Sinks.SystemConsole.

Our questions are:

1. Is this because Serilog is not supported with Net 6?
2. Is it a 32bit or 64bit version of kernal32.dll getting loaded from Serilog?

Follow-up for question 2:
When loading 32bit kernel32.dll, we get a bad image format exception, which means our application is 64bit and trying to load a 32bit assembly.
When replacing the 32bit with 64bit kernel32.dll, we get the following error:

> Unable to load DLL 'C:\kernel32.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified procedure could not be found. (0x8007007F)  at System.Runtime.InteropServices.NativeLibrary.LoadFromPath(String libraryName, Boolean throwOnError)  at System.Runtime.InteropServices.NativeLibrary.Load(String libraryPath)

Comment: 1. Serilog definitely is supported for .NET 6 - there's no reason why it should act differently in that context as it's just boring (but very neat!) .NET IL code. 2. If you look for the dependencies [on that tab re `Serilog.Sinks.Console`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/serilog.sinks.console), you can see it does not depend on anything exotic, hence there is no reason to believe there should be an x64 sensitivity caused by Serilog directly. So whatever is going on is down to the resolver you are talking about (I have no knowledge of it), and how it works in your context.

Comment: You did not specify whether you are running x86 or x64 - I'd suggest using SysInternals Process Monitor to analyze what dependency loads are happening/failing

Comment: @RubenBartelink It's x64.